# How to deal with abbreviations like 'etc.' at the end of parentheses which are closing a sentence?

Tags: punctuation, parentheses

In Hungarian, when there's a dot both inside and outside parentheses at the end of a sentence, we write it as follows:

> Sok állatom van (kutya, macska stb.).

(**Meaning:** *I've got many animals [dogs, cats, etc.]*)

I'm not sure though how do we write it in English.

1. *I've got many animals (dogs, cats, etc.).*
2. *I've got many animals. (dogs, cats, etc.)*
3. *I've got many animals (dogs, cats, etc.)*
4. *I've got many animals (dogs, cats, etc).*

Comment: Etc. is not an acronym, it's an abbreviation.

Comment: @Alenanno: Thanks, I often confuse acronyms with abbreviations. Corrected.

Comment: Number 1 in the OP's list is correct, except that plural examples would look more idiomatic: "I've got many animals (dogs, cats, etc.)."

Comment: @TheRaven: You're right, fixing it.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The dot in *etc.* is the dot for the abbreviation; the solutions are:

- If the abbreviation is outside of parentheses, you use only one dot, because it serves for *both* the abbreviation *and* the sentence-period:

> I've got many animals, such as dogs, cats, etc.

> I've got many animals: dogs, cats, etc.

- If it's inside the parentheses, like in this case, then you should use two dots, since *one* is for the abbreviation, *the other* is for the sentence:

> I've got many animals (dogs, cats, etc.).

Comment: how does this answer the OP's question? "Attachment A" does not get a period, so it's not relevant.

Comment: You're right. I'm editing it.

Comment: @Alenanno: Can you provide reference to your answer? This could also help for future lookups regarding similar issues

Comment: References include the [Languages Portal of Canada](http://www.noslangues-ourlanguages.gc.ca/bien-well/fra-eng/ponctuation-punctuation/etc-eng.html) and the [Chicago Manual of Style](http://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/qanda/data/faq/topics/Punctuation/faq0040.html)

Comment: I am not sure if this applies to English (but I feel it may apply), but in French, you can avoid the last period if there's one inside the parenthesis : “etc.)” is acceptable as much as “etc.).”: http://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/parens.asp